# Why can't CameraX zoom in a picture as larger as I need in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, zooming, android-camerax

I'm learning CameraX, and [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic) is a sample code.

I write a zoomX function based [CameraFragment.kt](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt). you can see the Code A. I think the function can zoom in a picture any time.

I find that a picture can be zoom in when I invoke it with s a small value, such as `zoomX(2f)`, `zoomX(3f)`, but the picture will not be zoom in again when I use a big value such as `zoomX(6.0f)`, `zoomX(7.0f)`... why?

**Code A**

```
   private lateinit var viewFinder: TextureView 
    private var preview: Preview? = null

    fun zoomX(orign: Float ){       
        val x=orign+1

        val singleWidth=viewFinder.width/x
        val singleHeight=viewFinder.height/x

        val left=viewFinder.width/2f-singleWidth/2f
        val right=left+singleWidth
        val top=viewFinder.height/2f-singleHeight/2f
        val bottom=top+singleHeight

        val my= Rect(left.toInt(), top.toInt(), right.toInt(), bottom.toInt())
        preview?.zoom(my)      
    }
```

Comment: You can use `CameraControl.setZoomPercentage()` from `androidx.camera.camera-core:1.0.0-alpha01`

Comment: Thanks! would you please show me more details about `CameraControl.setZoomPercentage()`? I can't find more document and sample code.

Comment: I was wrong. It's in `alpha07` which is not released yet. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f60a1ac99a4144d5bfb0529fa0c769f43eb10c9f The latest version is `alpha06`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a matter of tradition, but of `Futures`. Updating that [CameraXBasic](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/master/CameraXBasic) example from `1.0.0-alpha06` to `1.0.0-alpha08` breaks a lot, but CameraX [CameraControl](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl)  features these two methods:

- [`ListenableFuture<Void> setLinearZoom (float linearZoom)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl#setLinearZoom(float))

> Sets current zoom by a linear zoom value ranging from `0f` to `1.0f`.
>
> `linearZoom 0f` represents the minimum zoom while `linearZoom 1.0f` represents the maximum zoom. The advantage of `linearZoom` is that it ensures the field of view (FOV) varies linearly with the `linearZoom` value, for use with slider UI elements (while `setZoomRatio(float)` works well for pinch-zoom gestures).

- [`ListenableFuture<Void> setZoomRatio (float ratio)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/CameraControl#setZoomRatio(float))

> Sets current zoom by ratio.
>
> It modifies both current `zoomRatio` and `linearZoom` so if apps are observing `zoomRatio` or `linearZoom`, they will get the update as well. If the ratio is smaller than `CameraInfo.getMinZoomRatio()` or larger than `CameraInfo.getMaxZoomRatio()`, the returned `ListenableFuture` will fail with `IllegalArgumentException` and it won't modify current zoom ratio. It is the applications' duty to clamp the ratio.

Also see [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) and there's also [`CameraXExecutors`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/f6891e026b34931275ddaaad549411ffaf09f06b/camera/camera-core/src/main/java/androidx/camera/core/impl/utils/executor/).

---

Also see the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/camera) or the [commits](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+log/4cb7a5cbd2e20d3bf45cae63fea8436818576256..740cde70237dd276f8ad66dfe9528b1cdb5d54bb/camera/camera-core) ...for all the API changes, which break the CameraXBasic example. I won't explain any more of these API differences (since this wasn't the question), but [have forked](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/compare/master...syslogic:1.0.0-alpha08) it; see [issues #131](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/issues/131) (so far, at least the preview works there).

---

This is how it actually works:

```
val camera: Camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
val control: CameraControl = camera.cameraControl
control.setZoomRatio(5.0f)
```

Zoom ratios from `1.0f` until `8.0f` work on my Motorola XT1900:

```
val info: CameraInfo = camera.cameraInfo
val cameraId = (info as Camera2CameraInfoImpl).cameraId
val zoomRatio = info.getZoomRatio().value
val maxZoomRatio = info.getMaxZoomRatio().value
val minZoomRatio = info.getMinZoomRatio().value
val linearZoom = info.getLinearZoom().value
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  Could  you show a full sample code? so I can run and test it.

Comment: BTW, the project CameraXBasic can't be run after I  update it from 1.0.0-alpha06 to 1.0.0-alpha08.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that  the merge havn't yet done, so I can't pull it to my PC to test. Could you give me a temporary fork to pull code and test?

Comment: BTW, I'm a beginner of GitHub, I don't know how to pull from https://github.com/android/camera-samples/compare/master...syslogic:1.0.0-alpha08

Comment: At present , I ca only pull the fork caren/tap_to_focus, but it's based "1.0.0-alpha05"

Comment: @HelloCW see branch [1.0.0-alpha08](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/tree/1.0.0-alpha08) / [commits](https://github.com/syslogic/camera-samples/commits/1.0.0-alpha08/CameraXBasic)  (source of the PR).

Comment: Thanks. The function `fun setLinearZoom(camera: Camera, zoomLevel: Float)` require a `camera` object, how can I get it in your branch code?

Comment: @HelloCW That's `androidx.camera.core.Camera`, which should be already imported.

Comment: At present, I get the object camera using `camera=cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this as LifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, imageCapture, imageAnalysis, preview)`, is it right?

Comment: Thanks! You said `Sets current zoom by a linear zoom value ranging from 0f to 1.0f`, will `camera.cameraControl.setZoomRatio(5.0f)` cause error?

Comment: @HelloCW the documentation seems inaccurate; first tried `0.8f` but didn't work - and with `5.0f` it resulted in a zoomed preview (likely optical zoom; not sure what the max value is). Updated the answer with the code that works for me (the value might vary).

Comment: Hi, is it possible to zoom pass `0.0f - 1.0f` range? Like it's done in a magnifying glass apps or a telescope app where the camera can be zoom beyond the default max zoom limit of the Api.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Android tradition, zoom level exist between **`0`** and **`1`** like many other values..

`0` mean the lowest zoom level.

`1` mean the maximum zoom level.

It's a float value so you increase it like `0.1`, `0.2` , `0.9` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find out the max zoom value of the camera - using `getMaxZoom()` method.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getMaxZoom()

If you have used Camera Preview then you can set zoom in Camera preview using `Rect`. Like below -

```
PreviewConfig config = new PreviewConfig.Builder().build();
    Preview preview = new Preview(config);

    Rect rect = Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
    preview.zoom(rect)

    preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
        new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput previewOutput) {
                // Your code here. For example, use previewOutput.getSurfaceTexture()
                // and post to a GL renderer.
            };
    });

    CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, preview);
```

You may get more details from here - [Android Camera preview zoom using double finger touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120753/android-camera-preview-zoom-using-double-finger-touch)

Comment: Thanks! but CameraX doesn't support getMaxZoom().